# What is happening during Peer Review after editing a question?

Tags: discussion, edits, suggested-edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do suggested edits work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work)

Whenever I edit any question, it displays a message:

> **Thanks for your edit!**
>   This edit will be visible only to you until it is peer reviewed.

So I always wonder who does this peer review? Is it an automated system or, a manual process by moderator or high rep users?

Sometimes I get +2 reputation in a few seconds, but sometimes it takes time like half hour or more than hour. Why there is such delay?

Comment: I'll add my own 2 cents, based on my own experience - when the suggested edit is "simple" e.g. obvious grammar or code formatting it will be approved quickly, sometimes matter of seconds but when it's more "complicated" for example fixing coding error, adding/removing tags etc it might take more time as people are not sure if this is valid edit or not, thus leave the task of approving/rejecting to others.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[2k users](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/edit) can edit posts without delay. On top of that, [5k users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits) can use the review panel to approve or reject suggested edits.

I have attached a screenshot of this panel, see below.

- At the top of the page, new buttons will appear. The number in the brown box (5, in the picture) shows the number of *new* suggested edits.
  *(the orange number is showing the number of new flags for moderator attention)*
- Each suggested edit consists of a few sections:

  1. Summary *(purple circle)*
  2. Buttons to diff the edit. By default, the markdown diff is opened. The button at the top shows a diff of the rendered source. *(vertical red circle)*
  3. The usernames + reputation of the author and editor. The time of post creation and edit are also shown.
  4. `[Approve (1)] [Reject] [Improve]` *(red circle)*. These buttons can be clicked for reviewing. The Approve and Reject button can contain a `(1)`, indicating the number of votes for the specific decision. After reaching two votes, the edit has been reviewed, and the edit will be rejected or approved.
     The `Improve` button can be used to improve the suggested edit. When a suggested edit is approved, it is automatically marked as Useful (approved).
- When the edit is approved/rejected, the post collapses and moves to the top of the page *(green arrow)*.

Clicking on `[Reject]` will summon [a screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qKcij.png), in which the reviewer can elaborate your decision.

### [Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gr2r1.png): Review panel

[image: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits]

### [Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qKcij.png): Reject screen

[image]

Comment: "After reaching two votes, the edit has been reviewed, and the edit will be rejected or approved." If the first two votes disagree then a post will require three review votes.

Answer (score 3):

+5K users, post owners, users with edit privileges and moderators are the people who are reviewing.

We get a `review` link at the header (next to the `main | about | faq` links and a list of "Suggested Edits" that we can approve, reject or improve (the improve option simply mean we end up making an edit based on the suggested edit).

See the bottom of the privileges page for [approve tag wiki edits](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits).

Comment: That's incorrect - the post owner, users with full edit privileges and 5k users can review suggested edits.

Comment: @Mat - Thanks for the correction.