# Cannot make suggested edits on StackOverflow

Tags: support, edits, suggested-edits

I have been able to make suggested edits on StackOverflow for some time, but today (1st June 2012) I cannot see the Edit link on questions/answers anymore.

The last edit that I had accepted was the day before on 31st May 2012 - I can see it in my activity log and here is the  edit in question: [How to duplicate product template in opencart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10817941/how-to-duplicate-product-template-in-opencart)

The odd thing is that I can still click on the Review link at the top of the SO page so I am able to at least review questions but every time I expand a question/answer (or go directly to it) there is no Edit link available, only Link | Retag |Flag.

I can also see the Edit link on Meta despite having far less reputation on Meta compared to SO.

Has this privilege changed at all for StackOverflow or is this a bug?

Comment: The Suggested Edit Review Queue is full at the present time. There are 200 pending suggested edit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When users under the reputation 2000 proposed any editing on Question/Answer it requires **[Peer Review](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/117099/173001)**. So the edit goes to the Review Queue. As you can see in the picture that The Review queue is full at this time, you need to wait until some users with more than 5k reputation do the review work.

[image]

Comment: Now I understand. Of course I cannot see that since I don't have enough reputation! :)

Comment: **Great Power Comes with Great Responsibilities** @PeterMonks , once you have that much reputation, give regular time to review, it will help to others :)

Comment: I've (just) got enough rep to work through the edit queue, but it seems I'm limited to approving 50 a day. Is there a reason for that?

Comment: OK, I found the relevant question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87861/why-are-suggested-edit-votes-limited

Comment: Yes, you can approve or reject only 50 max edit per day @Widor

Comment: @Widor You can only approve (or reject, don't forget reject) 50 suggested edits in a day. Improve doesn't count against that quota. Having regularly hit the limit in the past few months, I find that 40/day was reasonable, but 50/day is a lot if you try to do things seriously. **Everyone with 5k rep on SO: please, we need more eyes on the [suggested edit queue](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits)!**