# Tell us when the suggested edit queue is full/busy on Stack Overflow

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, review, suggested-edits

I just asked [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134216/cannot-make-suggested-edits-on-stackoverflow/134217#comment373288_134217) asking why I couldn't see the edit link anymore to make suggested edits (I do not have 2000+ reputation yet to make edits on my own). It turns out I should have looked around Meta some more: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=suggested+edit+queue+full

The answer I got said that people with 2000+ reputation can see how many items are still in the suggested edit queue, but as I have not got that far yet I obviously cannot see that and therefore had no knowledge of this.

My suggestion is to tell us with less reputation that edits are unavailable at the moment. I'm not expecting the same thing as those who can see the suggested edit queue, but at least some visual indication/message on the Review page - it would save us from having to come asking on Meta all the time.

Comment: It would also be nice if reviewers has some sort of UI indication when the queue is full; it would tell them that it's important to go handle some of the requests sooner, rather than later.

Comment: So you now know that 'no *visible* edit link' means 'edit queue full'; and you're asking for a *visible* indication of 'edit queue full'. Am I missing something?

Comment: @AakashM calling something that is invisible a *visible* indication sounds a bit contradictory don't you think? It's not exactly in your face, which is why I think it could be improved

Comment: @AakashM also I didn't know that a missing edit link means a full edit queue because it is not obvious

Comment: Not a bad idea. The bigger issue remains that it happens consistently enough to warrant an indicator, though.

Comment: @Tim - Another option would be to fix the interface for reviewing so it works better, like [filtering out already processed items](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122368/filter-out-already-processed-items-from-the-suggested-edits) or *not* show a small selection in random order when the queue is full.

Comment: This feature has been implemented. [See answer below](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/293373/351462).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This makes a pretty good amount of sense. I'm imagining a pop-up appearing with "Sorry, the edit queue is currently full, wait for a bit" when you click the edit link, just like trying to downvote without enough rep leads to a message explaining why. I'm sure many other users are confused about the edit link being transient.

Comment: there are lots of users with reputation < 2K, when SO system is going to give popup to all the login user, which is not good.

Comment: The voting arrows give pop-ups to all non-users, which I would imagine to be larger than the group of < 2000 rep users trying to edit when the queue is full. Besides, the system already makes the "is queue full?" check in order to hide the edit links. Don't think it's an issue.

Comment: So basically you want to display edit link but when queue is full and someone click on edit link, it should display popup. But i guess this current system of hiding edit link is better.

Answer (score 18):

I'd like to drag this feature request in here as an answer, as I think it's a great (and simple?) solution to the problem:

[Always show the edit button on questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91172/always-show-the-edit-button-on-questions)

The tl;dr of the request is to always show the edit link below posts, but upon clicking, have that funky orange popup which says either;

1. We're not currently accepting any more edits as the queue is full. Check back soon.
2. We're not accepting suggested edits from this account due to poor edits in the past. Go home and cry.
3. You cannot edit this post yet, come back in 2 minutes.
4. ...etc

This behaviour fits in with the rest of the site;

1. We don't remove the vote icons when you run out of votes for the day
2. We don't remove the flag button when you run out of flags
3. We don't remove the close button when you run out of close votes.

Comment: I support this ... think it makes sense

Comment: The only problem I can see with this is I could spend a long time making lots of edits and doing a lot of work to the question/answer, but when I try to submit those edits it wouldn't let me save them. Would I have to lose all the hard work I've done just to redo them at a later time?

Comment: @PeterMonks: I was thinking you'd get the orange warning upon clicking the `edit` link (i.e. before you spend the time making the substantial edit); the system *wouldn't let* you actually make the edit, clicking the button would do nothing more than show the hint.

Comment: @PeterMonks: Although I suppose it's possible to click edit when the queue is *almost* full, spend ages making the edit, and then click submit when it is full; although this would also be the case with the *current* system as well as the proposal. I guess the system could be nice and let people who've already started an edit finish it.

Comment: @waffles: Is that a [meta-tag:status-planned] on http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91172/always-show-the-edit-button-on-questions I hear? ;)

Answer (score 8):

The edit button is no longer hidden if the edit queue is full. Instead, the button is greyed out with the hover text "Suggested edit queue is full".

[image: hover text when edit queue is full]

Comment: This is true for the Desktop version of the site, but on Mobile it still disappears entirely. There's a separate bug report about that here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161023/pending-edits-remove-the-edit-link-altogether-on-mobile-site

Answer (score 7):

I still get the error when pressing "Save" on an edit. The queue was made full while I was doing the edit. If I cancel and press "Edit" again, it says "Suggested edit queue is full".

So, the suggestion is: if a user already entered the edit mode, allow them to save the edit even if the queue size increased over the limit.

Comment: It would make sense to have some sort of grace period indeed. Seeing this question is already status-cometed it would be better to ask this as a new feature-request question.

Comment: Related [Notify me that the edit queue is full before I suggest an edit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/347615/289691)