# Temporary loss of permission to edit - what are the triggers for this permission to be suspended?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why don't I see an edit button under questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81681/why-dont-i-see-an-edit-button-under-questions)

I temporarily lost the ability to edit questions or answers on Stack Overflow, the link was simply missing. It's not for a couple of posts that have pending edits as I've had a browse around and it is universal.

My current edit stats are:

> Alex Hadley had 96 edit suggestions approved, and 6 edit suggestions rejected.

Which seems reasonable to me.

My questions are:

1. What are the factors that determine this sort of suspension of permissions?
2. What can one do to improve the situation in the future, and avoid such 'suspensions'?
3. How long do they normally last?
4. And also, is it possible for additional information to be provided when this occurs?

Note, this was only a temporary issue, but the question is still interesting I believe.

Comment: The suggested edit queue is full (200 pending edits). You'll have to wait for there to be space before you can submit any more, in the mean time, you can upvote [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134220/tell-us-when-the-suggested-edit-queue-is-full-busy-on-stackoverflow) [meta-tag:feature-request].

Comment: @Matt thanks for the info, and I agree with the feature-request too, so shall upvote that. More information is always welcome in such situations.

Comment: I think 5k+ rep users should go and clear the queue a bit... I'm out of votes for today so I can't help.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You have lost the ability to *suggest* edits (you need 2000 for actual edit permissions). But this doesn't have anything to do with you; the maximum amount of suggested edits that are allowed to be in the queue was just reached, so *nobody* can suggest edits until there's space in the queue again.

Comment: Many thanks for the answer balpha, I was unaware this happened, but it makes sense. I've also added my vote to Matt's link as this would be useful information.