# Cannot (suggest) edit question

Tags: support, edits, suggested-edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do suggested edits work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work)
>   [Temporary loss of permission to edit - what are the triggers for this permission to be suspended?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138733/temporary-loss-of-permission-to-edit-what-are-the-triggers-for-this-permission)

I always used to be able to suggest edits, but for some reason, the edit link is not visible at any question anymore.

I'm not someone editing just anything, only when I deem it neccesary. Such as incomprehensible question titles or wrong/missing tags. I didn't get any message such as 'too many edit suggestions were rejected' either, a thing I read on another question here on Meta SO.

Anyone who can enlighten me about this weird thing?

Comment: It seems the edit queue is full at the moment. There are 206 suggested edits waiting at this time.

Comment: Do you mean in general, for the whole of SO? Because I have never made as many as 206 edits.

Comment: In general. There were >200 suggested edits waiting to be approved.

Comment: ok, thanks. You can post this as an answer if you'd like me to accept.. @ThePower I gave you a +1 instead ;)

Comment: Thanks, but the duplicates explain it in more detail and better than I ever could. ;)

Comment: Oh.. I looked for this but couldn't find any similar quesitons.. hmm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the edit queue reaches a certain boundary, edit privileges for those with less than 2000 rep are withdrawn.

Your edit will be back in time :-)