# Pending edits remove the edit link altogether on mobile site

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, edits, suggested-edits, mobile-web

Is it intentional that the `EDIT` button is only on answers, but not on the question? I'm using the mobile site on SO...

<sub>(Also, really wish there was an image upload feature on mobile )</sub> :)

**edit** so it seems to be [only on this one question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14107263/hover-over-div-content-to-reveal-new-div-content) <sub>...uploading screenshot...wait..for..it..</sub>

[image: screenshot!]

Comment: Perhaps it had a pending edit? Maybe they didn't add the greyed-out effect on hover since you can't "hover for a tooltip"?

Comment: @animuson you're right, it's greyed out on the desktop site...why is this? and why not on mobile too? **edit** not anymore must have been b/c of pending edit.

Answer (score 6):

That question does (or did) indeed have a [pending suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1262097) attached to it. While an edit is pending, you cannot make further edits to it.

The edit link is greyed out on the main site and has a tooltip that displays when you hover over the edit link (for those who can't vote to approve/reject it), which explains that there is a pending edit and you cannot edit it.

Since mobile doesn't really have any way of "hovering" to get that tooltip, the edit link just isn't displayed (which used to be the normal behavior on the main site when the link didn't get greyed out). I suppose they *could* display the edit link greyed out on mobile, but that would cause just as much confusion as not displaying it.

Comment: thanks. So just curious, why not on desktop *and* mobile, change the `edit` to say `pending-edit` and make it non-clickable?

Comment: There's not exactly a lot of horizontal space there to be adding additional words, especially for those of us with many privileges. They really stack up.

Comment: haha guess i wouldn't know :/

Comment: Have you done A-B testing to back up your assertion that explaining why editing is not possible would be as confusing as not showing an edit link? I'm willing to accept that *showing an edit button that does nothing* would be confusing, but that would be silly.