# Mobile SE sites not allowing edits to edits

Tags: feature-request, edits, suggested-edits, mobile-web

When you have less than 2K rep and your edit goes in a queue, you are usually allowed to revise your edit while it is being reviewed, by clicking the edit button again on the question page. However, when on mobile SE sites, the edit button disappears when you have submitted an edit for review.

Editing [a comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/278434/mobile-so-site-not-allowing-edits-to-edits?noredirect=1#comment901883_278434) by [Shadow Wizard](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/152859/shadow-wizard) into the question:
It seems that the cause of this is when the mobile site hides the edit link (when there is a pending edit), it doesn't check *who* is making the edit, which means that it hides it for your own as well as other's edits.

Comment: Mobile app API is bit different than web app. It doesn't offer many features.

Comment: @Raju - OP is referring to "the mobile SO site", which does not use the mobile app API.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161023/pending-edits-remove-the-edit-link-altogether-on-mobile-site (the edit link is hidden instead of being disabled when there is a suggested edit, and it doesn't check who submitted the edit.)

Comment: As a workaround, you can click "full site" in the footer, and then edit. More difficult, but it should work.

Comment: This also happens on the iOS app. Brings up the edit changes instead of an edit to your edit in queue.

Comment: @John Yes, but I originally posted this on meta SO after noticing it there. Should I update the title to say "SE sites"?

Comment: Close voters: this is NOT a duplicate. The other one is a bug report marked as [tag:status-bydesign], meaning this is the intended behavior. This one here is a feature request **asking to change this existing behavior**. /cc @Majora320 if this gets closed please ping me and I'll reopen it.

Answer (score 5):

This is not very nice indeed. Preventing to show the edit button at all isn't quite useful. I understand you want to give your application users the best experience, and directing users to the desktop site isn't ideal, but some of us are power users and we really want to access that button, no matter if it is on the desktop or mobile site.

Editing your own edit is a feature that is the bare minimum SE should allow. There is no use in hiding it at all since the functionality behind it is already present in the mobile site (editing). It is the very same view.

Please allow us to edit our posts, and by extend those in review by allowing mobile users to review the suggested edit.

Answer (score 4):

When I want to edit my edit, I typically 'hit the back button' to get back to the edit page where you can edit your edit. There is also a 'full site' button on the bottom of the page in the mobile site, and, if you press it, you will no longer be on the mobile site, so you can do things like upload account images and edit your edits while on a mobile device.

Comment: Bountying this answer because it's a moderately useful workaround.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround is hit "share", then a link shows up like

```
https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/xxxxx/yyyyy
```

Now copy the number from `xxxxx` and ignore `yyyyy`. Type in your browser's address bar

```
https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/xxxxx/edit
```

You're now able to edit it (and generate a new or merged edit suggestion)

For questions, find the only number from the address bar, replace `xxxxx` with that number and you can edit the question.