# Edit button behaves inconsistently across platforms when edit queue is full

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits, user-interface, mobile-web, mobile-app

The 'edit' button has inconsistent behavior across devices when the suggested

[On a desktop, the 'edit' button will be grayed out.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/293373/351462)

[image: Desktop site: Edit button grayed out]

[On the mobile site, the edit button will be missing entirely.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161023/pending-edits-remove-the-edit-link-altogether-on-mobile-site)

[image: Mobile site: Edit button missing]

On the mobile app, the edit button has no indicator the queue is full. Users will not know the edit queue is full until clicking "submit" to save their changes.

[image: Mobile app: No error shown until submitting changes]

This inconsistent behavior can be very confusing from a user's perspective. When the edit queue is full, the edit button should be either be grayed out or show a message when clicked on all platforms.

Comment: The disappearing edit button on mobile drives me nuts. If I have edit approval privileges I could still use that button, but it's gone for no good reason!

Comment: [By design](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/161025/230261) (and possibly a duplicate depending on how you look at it, as the answer does address this, but I won't flag it, it's a bit up in the air).

Comment: (Also, related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225160/230261)