# Can the edit button be hidden if I am unable to edit?

Tags: feature-request, edits

I keep trying to edit meta posts (often just to see how a specific formatting thing is done) but when I click edit it just tells me:

[image]

Could it be made more obvious that the post can't be edited by me? Grey it out? Hide it completely?

The 'posts edited' statistic on my profile is greyed out so I don't see why this shouldn't be...

This above post is taken verbatim from [Can the edit button be hidden if I am unable to edit?](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3224/21924) on DBA Meta; the OP there was not interested in following up on Meta Stack Exchange, but as I have also had the same thought on other sites, I brought it over for consideration.

Comment: Note that you can still access the source code via the revisions list (which isn't linked to if there's only a single revision, but it's /posts/<post id>/revisions).

Comment: "Click here to collect your prize!" <click> "I'm sorry, you don't qualify."

Answer (score 2):

This actually *was* the old (and [IMHO better](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/198440/show-when-edits-are-pending-to-avoid-why-cant-i-edit-this#comment971260_298752)) situation:

> [image]

(It's not hidden, but grayed out – [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/161025/295232) suggests that it had been hidden in the past as well.) You had to hover over the edit link to see the reason why you couldn't edit; I understand that this isn't obvious for casual visitors but Stack Exchange has *a lot* of helpful tooltips.

It has been 'fixed' two years ago:

> Instead of greying out the edit button, the button will appear as normal and clicking it will bring up an error message with the same text that used to appear on hover

I've suggested a compromise [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/298797/editing-a-post-during-review-doesnt-show-an-edit-not-possible-message?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment971318_298797)

> can we have a compromise: the edit link can be clicked *but* it is grayed out?

but no reaction on that, alas ...

Comment: Is there a post that explains why the behaviour was changed to this? To me, greying it out (or not showing it at all) would be far preferable . . .

Comment: @JasonBassford It was probably proposed internally and implemented following internal discussion, as the only announcement of it was [a CM editing it into an FAQ answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/81701/20).

Comment: Probably the mouse hover tooltip was disliked because getting it to work on a mobile device was literally hit and miss - often clicking through. Still greying it out would be great, unless people presume that it's grey *because* they are on a Meta and think that they ought to be able to click it in any event; leading back to a reopening of this.